# InvalidOperationException using SqlServerRetryingExecutionStrategy without user-initiated transactions

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, azure-functions

I'm getting an intermittent InvalidOperationException occurring in a ServiceBusTriggered Azure Function:

> The configured execution strategy 'SqlServerRetryingExecutionStrategy' does not support user-initiated transactions. Use the execution strategy returned by 'DbContext.Database.CreateExecutionStrategy()' to execute all the operations in the transaction as a retriable unit.

The message is pretty clear, but there are no user-initiated transactions in the code. The code is very simple:

```
try
{
    Context.Add<TEntity>(entity);
    await Context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ...
}
```

The context is registered as scoped using DI.

I was looking online for answers, but all the explanations point toward user-initiated transactions, which there are none in the code.

Is there any other reason or explanation for this exception?
Is it possible that in some conditions the SaveChanges operation would be seen as a user-initiated transaction?
Is it possible for transactions from stored procedures to cause this?